# How to parametrize a parameter in pytest?

Tags: python, testing, parameters, nested, pytest

Sometimes with pytest we start to parametrize a test function:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("user", [WebUser(), BusinessUser(), AdminUser()])
def test_foo(user):
    ...
```

And then realize that some of the parameters would themselves have possible variants. Of course for simple concepts and short lists of parameters the simplest way to do this is to duplicate:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("user", [WebUser("bob", age=12), WebUser("alice", age=56), BusinessUser("v1"), BusinessUser("v2"), AdminUser()])
def test_foo(user):
    ...
```

However this breaks tests readability quite fast when the number of variants gets big and very different for each "kind" in the first parameter. Is there a way to do this in a more elegant/modular way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Answering my own question to share at least one way of doing this - please excuse me for advertising my own lib here but I really felt that this question was missing in SO. Feel free to propose other alternatives, this is a living topic !)*

One way to do this is with the `pytest-cases` plugin.

```
import pytest
from pytest_cases import parametrize_with_cases

class UserCases:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("name,age", [("bob", 12), ("alice", 56)])
    def user_web(self, name, age):
        return WebUser(name, age)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("version", ["v1", "v2"])
    def user_business(self, version):
        return BusinessUser(version)

    def user_admin(self):
        return AdminUser()


@parametrize_with_cases("user", cases=UserCases, prefix="user_")
def test_foo(user):
    pass
```

yields:

```
test_foo[web-bob-12]
test_foo[web-alice-56]
test_foo[business-v1]
test_foo[business-v2]
test_foo[admin]
```

This is recursive so you can use `@parametrize_with_cases` on any case function.
See [pytest-cases documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) for details.